# Python UNO and Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, libreoffice, uno

I am working with Python UNO using the "internal" (Libreoffice is the host process) version where the Python interpreter lives within Libreoffice/Openoffice. I would like to make the code nonblocking...that is once the code gets called as a macro, it starts a second thread and returns the main thread back to Office so that it does not block the UI while it continues to run a very lengthy process (10-20 minutes execution time).

When I tried exactly this, LibreOffice freezes forever. I've searched just about everywhere but other than an odd reference to importing scipy in a second thread and then blocking while waiting on that thread (myrhread.join()), there seems to be nowhere that this is done.

Alternatively, is it possible to create a new ServiceManager so that I could invoke a second process and then link back to the ServiceManager so that I can return back to LibreOffice in the normal way without locking it up with a "ghost thread"?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please post a simplified version of the code you have tried so far, the one that freezes.  A couple of questions: Is the PyUNO code getting invoked as a macro (for example `Tools -> Macros -> Run Macro`) or from outside using a listening instance?  Also, what does the lengthy process accomplish - does it modify the Writer document, or do something outside, for instance create a file somewhere else in the operating system?

Comment: As stated above, it is invoked as a macro (lives inside the LibreOffice process). If it was outside then threading would not be necessary. The reason that the code is slow is that I found after experimentation that creating an annotation is pretty slow. I need to insert something like 1500 cell annotations. Without the annotations it runs in seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I found the answer here:

[LibreOfficeForum Threading Example](http://web.archive.org/web/20150509204228/http://en.libreofficeforum.org/node/5468)

For simple long-running tasks where it would otherwise block the UI thread, this works very well. The relevant code is as follows:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import uno

t = None

def test_worker(doc):

    # Wait 30 seconds for demonstration purposes
    sleep(30)

    # Get the 1st sheet in the document and insert text into cell A1
    doc.Sheets.getByIndex(0).getCellByPosition(0,0).String = "I'm back"

def delayedRun(*args):
    global t
    doc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    t = Thread(target = test_worker, args = (doc,))
    t.start()

g_exportedScript = delayedRun,
```

Comment: It's a good answer.  I would have been happy to help but I needed more information.  Next time after asking a question, please check on it periodically to address any comments.

Comment: For others who find this answer, `global t` and `t = None` is considered to be poor Python code and also not needed in this example. So remove those lines before adapting into a project.